# Parsing inline javascript variable to script src as parameter

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS, so please bear with me if this question might not make sense.

Is it possible to parse an inline js value to a js src value?

Suppose I have this inline js.

```
<script>
    window.foo = window.foo || {};
    window.foo.cam = { 'status';'logged-out'};
</script>
```

This is the javascript src which I like to parse the above value to to %value%.

```
<script src="http://bar.com/js.php?position=bottom&login_status=%value%"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do if you dynamically add the script tag to the DOM with Javascript:

```
<div id="s_tag_container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.foo = window.foo || {};
    window.foo.cam = {'status': 'logged-out'};
    var s_tag = document.createElement('script');
    s_tag.src = 'http://bar.com/js.php?position=bottom&login_status='+window.foo.cam.status;
    document.getElementById('s_tag_container').appendChild(s_tag);
</script>
```